# How to make my code be more efficient in terms of both time/space complexity

Tags: python, pandas, processing-efficiency

It is quite long so I'm not sure I can ask you to review my code. But I have no choice indeed.

What I'm doing is analyzing the Korean language. To do this, first I collect data and loaded the data via `pd.DataFrame`. Then, I chunk the text data ('contents' column in the dataframe) into morpheme units by using `TextAnalyzer`. The below is an example of the process so far:

```py
data = [document1, document2, ...] # dataframe.loc[:, 'contents']
tokenizer  = TextAnalyzer()
for item in data:
    tokenizer.ma.analyze_wordform_parsed(item) # get sentences in the document, and split the sentence into morphemes
# results
[[(morpheme1 of sentence1, pos1 of sentence1), ..], [(morpheme1 of sentence2, pos1 of sentence2), ...] # for 1 document
```

Now I have morphemes and their corresponding part of speech. And I need this information to get the original word so I made a dictionary for saving the information into `M2W`.

For the collected documents, what I want to do is extracting keywords and sentiment words. For the collection of the morphemes, I need to find sentiment words. Therefore, I also split the sentiment words into their corresponding morphemes. The sentiment words are saved in `POS_DICT`, `NEU_DICT` and `NEG_DICT`. The sentiment morphemes and their corresponding POS are:

```py
[[(sentiment morpheme1, POS1), (sentiment morepheme2, POS2), ...), ...], ...] # the inside list representing morephemes/POS for a sentiment word
```

So I used the Boyer Moore algorithm to find the patterns which are the sentiment words. The work has proceeded through [pandas-multiprocess](https://github.com/xieqihui/pandas-multiprocess). The blow is the entire code of the process and I made them as a class.

```py
class KeywordAnalyzer:
    def __init__(self, morph_path: str="../rsc/resource/NULL/", sent_dict: str="../rsc/sentiment_dict/") -> None:
        self.sent_dict = sent_dict
        self.tokenizer = TextAnalyzer(dict_path=morph_path)
        self.init_sent_dict(self.sent_dict)
        # keyword list
        self.KEYWORDS_POS = {"NNIN1", # 고유명사
                        "NNIN2", # 일반명사
                        "NPR" # 술어명사
                        } # POS for part of speech
        self.init_sent_dict(sent_dict)

    def init_sent_dict(self, sent_dict: str):
        self.POS_DICT = set() # POS for positive
        self.NEG_DICT = set()
        self.NEU_DICT = set()
        
        self.M2W = dict() # Morph to Word

        def get_morphs(file):
            words = [item.strip() for item in file]
            morphs = [tuple(self.tokenizer.ma.analyze_wordform_parsed(item)[0]) for item in words]
            return words, morphs
    
        for item in Path(sent_dict).glob("*"):
            with open(item) as f:
                if item.name.split('_')[1] == "POSITIVE":
                    words, morphs = get_morphs(f)
                    self.POS_DICT.update(morphs)
                elif item.name.split('_')[1] == "NEUTRALITY":
                    words, morphs = get_morphs(f)
                    self.NEU_DICT.update(morphs)
                elif item.name.split('_')[1] == "NEGATIVE":
                    words, morphs = get_morphs(f)
                    self.NEG_DICT.update(morphs)
                
                temp_dict = {morph:word for word, morph in zip(words, morphs)}
                self.M2W.update(temp_dict)

    def get_keywords(self, data: pd.Series) -> Tuple[List[str], List[str], List[str], List[str]]:
        # make tokens
        tokens = self.tokenizer.morpheme_analyzer(data.loc['contents'])
        
        pos_words = []
        neu_words = []
        neg_words = []
        rels = []
        
        for item in tokens:
            sentence = list(itertools.chain(*item))
            pos_words.extend(self._get_pos_words(sentence))
            neu_words.extend(self._get_neu_words(sentence))
            neg_words.extend(self._get_neg_words(sentence))
        
            rels.extend(self._get_rel_words(sentence))

        return pos_words, neu_words, neg_words, rels # Tuple[[sents_1, ...], [rels_1, ...]]
    
    def _get_pos_words(self, sentence: List[Tuple[str, str]]) -> List[str]:
        words = [self.M2W[sent_morph] for sent_morph in self.POS_DICT if self._boyer_moore(sent_morph, sentence)]
        return words
    
    def _get_neu_words(self, sentence: List[Tuple[str, str]]) -> List[str]:
        words = [self.M2W[sent_morph] for sent_morph in self.NEU_DICT if self._boyer_moore(sent_morph, sentence)]
        return words
    
    def _get_neg_words(self, sentence: List[Tuple[str, str]]) -> List[str]:
        words = [self.M2W[sent_morph] for sent_morph in self.NEG_DICT if self._boyer_moore(sent_morph, sentence)]
        return words
    
    def _get_rel_words(self, sentence: List[Tuple[str, str]]) -> List[str]:
        keywords = [morph for morph, pos in sentence if pos in self.KEYWORDS_POS]
        return keywords
    
    def _boyer_moore(self, pattern: Iterable, text: Iterable) -> bool:
        def find(pattern, char):
            for i in range(len(pattern) -2, -1, -1):
                if pattern[i] == char:
                    return len(pattern) - i - 1
            return len(pattern)

        M = len(pattern)
        N = len(text)
        i = 0

        while i <= N - M:
            j = M - 1
            while j >= 0:
                if pattern[j] != text[i + j]:
                    move = find(pattern, text[i + M - 1])
                    break
                j = j - 1
            if j == -1:
                return True
            else:
                i += move
        return False
```

I'm not sure my explanation is straightforward. Thanks for reading.

Comment: This question is asking for a review of working code, so belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you can figure out a specific question about 1 part of the code you could potentially post it here, however

Comment: Your code is not very time-complex apart from the Boyer Moore algorithm so maybe you should ask a specific question about optimizing that?

Comment: @Stuart Okay thanks.